# Encrypt ubuntu 14.04 home directory with services accessing them without login

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, service, init.d, disk-encryption

I have few services which gets started as soon as server boots up. Now i would like to encrypt my home directory. Will services work properly if i do so?
Code for those services is present in the home directory and accesses some json files, cron jobs and mongoDB.

Comment: Why are system services looking for files in a user home directory? This is generally not good practice.

Comment: what is the recommended path for system services? @MichaelHampton